# Issue with connecting two devices with Ethernet cable

Tags: windows-10, networking, ethernet

I have a laptop and PC to be connected via Ethernet cable. The laptop has internet through WiFi and I would like to share this internet with the PC.

I had earlier set up these for file sharing and internet sharing, but something got messed up. I have removed the Network adapters to reset them.

`NIRMAL-LAPTOP` and `NIRMAL-PC` are the two devices.

Internet sharing is working fine. But issues with file sharing.

I had turned on Network discovery and File and Printer Sharing. But they are not accessible/discoverable.

Troubleshooting at `NIRMAL-PC` shows an error

```
Windows can't communicate with the device or resource (NIRMAL-LAPTOP)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you really want the PC to *"share"* an Internet connection from the laptop?  That would require the laptop to always be up and running for the PC to get its connection.  Not to mention burdening the laptop with extra network load.